# Testing YAML config parser with pytest

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, pytest

I'm writing a package that uses a YAML config parser in multiple contexts.

I need to test the parser with `py.test`, and I'm writing a class for each context where the parser sub-package gets applied.

So I need to load a YAML file for each class, and have it available to every test in that class.

Is my example below a good approach or is there something else I should be doing?

```py
import pytest
import yaml
import my_package

class context_one:
    @pytest.fixture
    def parse_context(self):
        return my_package.parse.context # module within parser for certain context

    @pytest.fixture
    def test_yaml_context(self):
        with open('test_yaml.yml') as yaml_file:
            return yaml.load(yaml_file)

    def test_validation_function1(self,parse_context,test_yaml_context):

        test_yaml = test_yaml_context['validation_function1']

        # test that missing key raises error
        with pytest.raises(KeyError):
            parse_context.validation_function1(test_yaml['missing_key_case'])


        # test that invalid value raises error
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            parse_context.validation_function1(test_yaml['invalid_value_case'])
```

It works. I thought I'd ask because I don't find much in the py.test docs, even though I feel that something along these lines would be sort of a common use case.

Specifically:
not sure **why** I need to have the fixtures

- if I load the YAML at the test module level, the tests can't find it--this is just the way py.test works?
- should I just import the my_package.parse_context at the test module level?

Comment: Why do you worry about how your tests are running, they are just test. You **should** worry about your use of  PyYAML and especially `yaml.load()`, which can, as described in the PyYAML documentation, be unsafe (wipe disk or worse on uncontrolled input). As it is  **never** necessary to use it in practise, why run that  risk in the first place? Use `safe_load()`, extended with any constructors you might need.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about security issues with YAML. In this case, though, the YAML is written by the users themselves as configuration files that the package uses. So unless they're trying to hack themselves (probably not), that shouldn't be a concern in this case. Sorry if I wasn't clear in what I mean by config files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need them. I'd define `setup_module()` to read and parse test_yaml.yml once for all tests.
2. No. Strange problem. If I would debug it I'd log the current directory. Or simply open the file related to the test file: `open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_yaml.yml'))`.
3. Yes, why not?

Comment: Hmm. Okay, so when I load the .yml into a variable *outside* a class, then the methods *inside* the class can find that variable, but when I load the .yml *inside* the class, then the methods *cannot* find it. I had tried writing an __init__ method for the class and storing the .yml in a property of the class, but defining an __init__ makes pytest throw an error. Is there something I'm not understanding about OO code here?

Comment: pytest doesn't like test classes, it prefers functions for tests. You can test your classes in test functions.